# $.ajax call doesn't set cookies with crossDomain and xhrFields.withCredentials set true

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax request call from a jquery script to a cross domain server. I did include the options `crossDomain: true, xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to the ajax call. The server is set up with cors (`{origin: RegExp('\w*.mydomain.com'), credentials: true}`). But somehow the ajax request doesn't set the session cookie in the request. Any ideas?

[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBPPI.png)

[Options Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tiFX.png)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDM2v.png)

Comment: Welcome. I'm far from an expert with these things, but you're showing the `OPTIONS` request that is made before the actual request. That one is just the preflight request that checks the CORS related stuff, so `withCredentials` won't have an effect on it. I suppose this request fails, which should generate a warning on your client/browser's console.

Comment: Also I doubt you can use a regexp as your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value. This might explain why the preflight request fails. `*.mydomain.com` (as a string) would usually work, but not when requesting credentials. You'll have to specify exact domain names, I believe.

Comment: Updated the question. I also tried to set origin to the exact url. The cookie is still not set. @Jeto

Comment: @Jeto The preflight request didn't fail. I just didn't notice the real put request afterwards. The options request was successful even with the regexp.

Comment: Is the remote domain different from the client's one? Please show your entire `$.ajax` statement.

Comment: @Jeto I have a node server running on example.mydomain.com which is my webapp. Users are authenticated there and then stored in a cookie with client-sessions. For this webapp I built another node server as a configuration server running on config.mydomain.com. There I want to authenticate the user by reading the cookie.

Comment: Yes, common use. I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work at the moment, except maybe a weird `Content-Type` header that isn't allowed during the preflight request. That's why I asked if you could share the `$.ajax` statement.

Comment: @Jeto `$.ajax({ crossDomain: true, xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, url: 'http://config.mydomain.com/example', type: 'PUT', data }).done(function() { refreshConfig() })`

Comment: Should work fine. Note that `crossDomain: true` is not needed and is irrelevant here

Comment: @charlietfl Should work fine. But doesn't work fine. That's why I'm here